# What to do about edit vandalism done by OP?

Tags: discussion, edits, flags, rollbacks

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35305382/5) is an edit that obviously destroys the original question. It has been undone, so everything is fine.

Still I wonder what to do about it. Can the edit - done by the OP! - be flagged? Can the OP be "flagged" for such behaviour? Or is it just OK? (No!)

Comment: Someone didn't want anyone to know they were getting homework help, I bet.

Comment: I downvoted the original question for poor formatting, but I guess it's somewhat pointless.   I'm sure that 'Member for 6 days' will just open another account in order to get SO contributors to do next weeks' homework question.